# bug of feature of g++ linker

Tags: c++, g++

I have 3 files

test.h

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>
std::unique_ptr<int> createInt();
```

test.cpp - pay attention test.h wasn't included

```
#include <memory>

std::shared_ptr<int> createInt()
{
    return std::make_shared<int>();
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "test.h"
int main()
{
    createInt();
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles with out any problems with 
`g++ -Wall -Wextra main.cpp test.cpp`

And fails in runtime:

```
./a.out
a.out(3632,0x7fff78ba9300) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fe290404c68: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

However Visual studio doesn't compile such source with LNK1120 error.

Why g++ linker doesn't fail such code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return-type is not part of the signature for overload resolution, only name and argument types. It's in the C++ specification.

The compiler will emit a reference to a function named `createInt` taking no arguments, and the linker will find such a symbol.

The return-type mismatch will lead to *undefined behavior* at run-time.

Comment: I understood this. But why was it done so? In my opinion this is strange and error leading approach. As I wrote in Visual studio return-type is a part of the signature.